# Save a local file URL .m3u8 stream using youtube-dl

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming, codec, youtube-dl

I have a local `.m3u8` file containing stream information. I would like to use `youtube-dl` or a fork to download the stream.

When I pass the local file to youtube-dl it gives the error that it is expecting a URL:

```
youtube-dl ~/STREAM.m3u8
```

> ERROR: '/Users/USER/STREAM.m3u8' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:/Users/USER/STREAM.m3u8" ) to search YouTube

when I pass an explicit file URL it gives:

```
youtube-dl file://~/STREAM.m3u8
```

> [generic] STREAM: Requesting header
> WARNING: Could not send HEAD request to file://~/STREAM.m3u8: <urlopen error file:// scheme is explicitly disabled in youtube-dl for security reasons>
> [generic] STREAM: Downloading webpage
> ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error file:// scheme is explicitly disabled in youtube-dl for security reasons> (caused by URLError('file:// scheme is explicitly disabled in youtube-dl for security reasons'))

Does `youtube-dl` not work with local URLs? What is the security reason for which this is disabled?

Is there any flag or configuration change to enable the download of remote contents from a local file URL stream `.m3u8` file?

Comment: Not an answer, but `ffmpeg` is likely what you want to use, assuming you want to download some media from that local `.m3u8` file.

Comment: Why not just fire up some random HTTP server? Depending on what the playlist contains it won’t work anyway.